# How to integrate greatest integer function x from -1 to 2?

Tags: integration

Can some one please help me to solve $\int_{-1}^{2}\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor dx$ ?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** You may write your integral as
$$
\int_{-1}^{2}[x]dx=\int_{-1}^0[x]dx+\int_0^1[x]dx+\int_1^{2}[x]dx
$$ then it is easier to evaluate each part.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\int_{-1}^{2}[x]dx$$
Splitting  the limits
$$=\int_{-1}^{0}[x]dx+\int_{0}^{1}[x]dx+\int_{1}^{2}[x]dx$$
$$=\int_{-1}^{0}(-1)dx+\int_{0}^{1}(0)dx+\int_{1}^{2}(1)dx$$
$$=-\int_{-1}^{0}dx+0+\int_{1}^{2}dx$$
$$=-[x]_{-1}^{0}+[x]_{1}^{2}$$
$$=-(0-(-1))+(2-1)$$ $$=-1+1=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-1}^{2} dx=\\\int_{-1}^{0}\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor dx+\int_{0}^{1}\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor dx+\int_{-1}^{2}\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor dx=\\\int_{-1}^{0}(-1) dx+\int_{0}^{1}(0) dx+\int_{-1}^{2}1 ds\\=-1+0+1=0$$